# How to get count of visible rows in Grid View?

Tags: c#, .net, gridview

I Have GridView with both visible and invisible rows in it,

But i just want count of only visible Rows in that grid

i have tried this

```
int rowCount = gv_SPAvailable.Rows.Count(row => row.IsVisible);
```

But i could not get, is there any other way, any one please help

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
int rowCount = gv_SPAvailable.Rows.GetRowCount(DataGridViewElementStates.Visible);
```

Answer (score 1):

Also these code is working fine

```
     int numVisible = 0; 
        foreach(GridViewRow row in gv_SPAvailable.Rows) 
        { 
            if(row.Visible == true) 
            { 
                numVisible += 1; 
            } 
        }
```